# Pass anchor tag attributes to the href page in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

example.html contains:

```
<a href="mypage.html" data-str="foo">Test</a>
```

Is it possible to access the value of `data-str` inside `mypage.html`?

Comment: You could pass that value as part of a query string to mypage.html?data-str=foo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the values are part of the html on example.html.

You will have to pass it through as querystring to access this value.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, as @Kami wrote...

> The values are part of the html on example.html

That's absolutely correct and now I think you have **2** alternatives to achieve what you need...

**1.** Use `querystring`

**2.** Store the `data-str` in a `cookie` (created at client side using `jQuery`) for use it in other pages of your `site`.

---

I prefer option **2** and this example will help you...

---

### Using cookies...

Use this plugin: *jquery.cookie*

https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js

Create a cookie from `data-str`...

```
//get data attribute
var str = $('.data-to-query').data('str');
//create a cookie called 'data-str' with 'str' variable value
$.cookie('data-str', str);
```

Then in other `html` pages just get the cookie using this:

```
var str = $.cookie('data-str');

//then you can do other things like this...
if(str != null) {
  //do something when cookie value is defined
}
```

And, if you want to remove the cookie just do this at any `html` page you were situated:

```
$.cookie('data-str', null);
```

Just to know, it's obvious that `jquery.cookie` plugin and also `jQuery` must be imported in all your `html` pages.

---

That's all. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to have a dynamic data attribute, but keep the referring url the same, you could do something like this:

Html

```
<a href="mypage.html" data-str="foo" class="data-to-query">Test</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('.data-to-query').click(function(){
  window.open($(this).attr('href') + '?str=' + $(this).data('str'),'_self');
  return false;
});
```